# Rails soft delete child record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 4.2

I have a parent class that accepts nested attributes for its children.

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :kids
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :kids, allow_destroy: true
end

class Kid < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent

  def destroy
    if some_count > 0
      self.hidden = true
    else
      self.destroy
    end
  end
end
```

I sometimes want to set the hidden flag on the child instead of deleting it. I am doing this via `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. I need this decision to be set on the server side, I can't have users deciding whether to destroy or hide.

But not destroying raises `ActiveRecord::RecordNotDestroyed - Failed to destroy the record:`

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: from the doc "Raised by `ActiveRecord::Persistence#destroy!` when a call to destroy would return false." (source : http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/RecordNotDestroyed.html) => you probably called `.destroy!` on a record and this method returns false, which raises the error

Answer (score 2):

The error is thrown because you got into infinite loop (you are calling `destroy` method within `destroy` method). Use super instead. Also you need to save hidden column change to the database. In this case it should be safe to use `update_column` (no validation and no callbacks are triggered, no other columns are saved to the database)

```
class Kid < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent

  def destroy
    if some_count > 0
      update_column(:hidden, true)
    else
      super
    end
  end
end
```

To answer other question you need to explain what some_count is. :)

Comment: I don't think using `update_column` is a good idea here because, as you said, it skips the validationd and callbacks which can be very important. IMO, a regular `update_attributes(hidden: true)` should be used in this case

Comment: @MrYoshiji - Problem with `update_attributes` is that it will also save all other unsaved attributes (as it literally calls save internally), which might not be intended when "destroying" the object. I am really missing a method in rails which would update a single column running all the callbacks, however I agree that `update_attributes` might be slightly safer here.